# How to Prevent this type of Suggestion in Sublime Text 3?

Tags: sublimetext3, autosuggest

Even before I start writing code, some meaningless suggestions are coming which make no sense... Preventing me to use Multi cursor feature... It's coming from where and how can I stop this?

[image: Suggestion example]

List of my Packages, hope it helps:

> ```
> A File Icon
> AdvancedNewFile
> Alignment
> Auto Semi-Colon
> AutoFileName
> Autoprefixer
> BetterSnipperManager
> ColorHelper
> CSS To SASS And Stylus Converter
> Emmet
> Hover Image Preview
> Inc-Dec-Value
> jQuery
> Less Tabs
> Local History
> Material Theme 
> One Dark Color Scheme 
> Package Control
> Sass 
> SASS Build 
> SFTP 
> SideBarEnhancements 
> SublimeLinter
> SublimeLinter-jshint
> Theme - One Dark 
> UnusedCSSFinder
> View In Browser 
> zzz A File Icon zzz
> ```

Comment: Do you use Fuzzy​File​Path package?

Comment: No, I am not using that package

Comment: Can you show your package list which is installed your sublime?

Comment: Sure, I have added the package names in question, please check

Comment: Can you disable AutoFileName package and restart your sublime. I think it'll work.

Comment: You got it my friend, it's solved as you said according to suggestion of their admin:
https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/how-to-prevent-this-type-of-suggestion-in-sublime-text-3/34194/3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just disable Packages which autocomplete path of files:

```
AutoFileComplete
AutoFileName
Fuzzy​File​Path
```

Just uninstall and restart your editor :)

Comment: The problem was because of "AutoFileName" package by the way.

Comment: I just added this comment for to mark as solution :)

Comment: Thanks... Which package can I use to get image sourcing done?
"AutoFileName" was doing this work great but causing problem as we already discussed. Which package you suggest me to use?

Comment: I am trying FuzzyFilePath...

It's putting a "\" sign before which is not needed and so image source is not working.

It should be:
<img src="img/logo _2.png"

It is giving:
<img src="/img/logo _2.png"

Can I solve this by any means? Or please suggest an alternative way/package; thanks!

Comment: Okayy. If I found any useful package I'll share it :)

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution from Sublime Text admin.

**"AutoFileName"** package was causing problem. Now it's solved as soon as removed the package...